# Get age from DOB - Dask

Tags: datetime, dask

How would I include a new column called "Age_cust" when I have a a "DOB" column?

```
from datetime import date
today = date.today()

ddf = ddf.assign(Age_cust=cust.map_partitions(lambda x: x['DOB'] - today))
```

From this I get the error

```
ValueError: Metadata inference failed in `lambda`.

You have supplied a custom function and Dask is unable to 
determine the type of output that that function returns. 

To resolve this please provide a meta= keyword.
The docstring of the Dask function you ran should have more information.

Original error is below:
------------------------
TypeError("unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'DatetimeArray' and 'datetime.date'")
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you are facing stems from using different different datetime formats.

`x[“dob”] - dask.dataframe.to_datetime(datetime.datetime.today())`

is your solution

Answer (score -1):

This might not be the most efficient way and I am unfamiliar with DASK but the following works, assuming your data frame is called df:

```
import datetime as dt
from datetime import date

year = df["DOB"].dt.year.values
month = df["DOB"].dt.month.values
day = df["DOB"].dt.day.values

today = date.today()

age = []
for i in range(len(year)):
    age.append(today.year - year[i] - ((today.month, today.day) < (month[i], day[i])))

df["age"] = age
```